# How to have firefox extension contact webpage to change Font-Size? (SOLVED)

Tags: javascript, json, accessibility, firefox-addon, font-size

Writing my first firefox extension and I am trying to have it change the font-size on a webpage to one entered by the user.

However my extension at present does not seem to send out any request at all to change the font-size (or if it is not meant to actually contact the webpage as I somewhat expect is failing to change the font-size at all for the user anyway).

What does an extension need to have in it in order to try and change the styling of a webpage in this way?

I have tried having my extension use Content-Scripts and Background scripts, have used seperate and singular javascript files to handle the action, have tried text input and button presses from the user, and have tried to have the javascript see where fontsize is in the webpage and change it.

In the JSON file my extension has activeTab and contextMenus permissions, and when it is a Content-Script it is set to match on ["<all_urls>"].

I have worked out where I went wrong and have fixed the issue.

What I ended up doing was going through every tag name for text (p, h1, h2, etc) and then changing their size to the size set by the user. This is not an optimal solution but for my purposes it does work.

Comment: You intend to allow a user to modify the DOM through the use of a firefox addon. You also wish to allow the user to do this on all pages.    You probably already know, but you cannot get an id or class to do so. You'll need to do it by tag name, and iterate through each of them in a loop, to set the font size for these elements.

Comment: I noticed that you marked your own question as solved. Please post an answer of what you did to solve your problem. This may end up helping other people in the future, who may come across this in their search: https://xkcd.com/979/